# OSX: Filtering searched files in API?

Tags: swift, macos, search, filenames

I like to search for some files, matching a name criteria. Of course I can read all files and then check in my app, if they match or not. Simply like this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()    
let en = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: the_path)   

while let element = en?.nextObject() as? String {
    if element.hasPrefix("IMG_123") {
        // found....
    }
}
```

BUT, I'm searching on a larger external volumne over WLAN. So it needs a long time to transfer all the filenames and then drop them. Is there a way, to give the condition to the API call, so it returns, only if a matched file was found?

Comment: what do you mean with `larger external volume over WLAN` ? You can easily read & write file to disk with `FileManager` but i do not get the problem.

Comment: A server offers more than 1.000.000 files. If I need 20 files, beginning with "IMG_123456", then I need to transfer 1.000.000 file names via Wifi, drop 999.980 files and keep only 20. I only want to transfer the found 20 file names from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems that there is no such option/function. I now simply search through the entire structure and do the filtering within my loop.